# Lifebook E546 touchpad on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

My touchpad never worked since install. I suspect wrong drivers but cannot find out what drivers do I need.

Fujistu Lifebook E546

Here is dmesg -T output:

```
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:01 2017] psmouse serio2: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x470f00)
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:01 2017] psmouse serio2: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x50, 0x12, 0x09.
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:01 2017] psmouse serio2: elantech: Elan sample query result 01, 27, 86
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:02 2017] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input394
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:04 2017] psmouse serio2: Touchpad at isa0060/serio2/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:04 2017] psmouse serio2: Touchpad at isa0060/serio2/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:04 2017] psmouse serio2: Touchpad at isa0060/serio2/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:04 2017] psmouse serio2: Touchpad at isa0060/serio2/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:04 2017] psmouse serio2: Touchpad at isa0060/serio2/input0 lost sync at byte 6
[Sun Jun  4 18:15:04 2017] psmouse serio2: issuing reconnect request
```

I have tried unloading and loading module but did not make any difference.

It might be related to my keyboard problem, keys get unresponsive or stuck and loops last input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case I resolved this by adding psmouse.proto=imps into /etc/default/grub in line where "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX":

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.proto=imps"
```

and then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

unfortunately adding configuration into /etc/modprobe.d/ folder did not work so I had to add this into grub config itself.

It also works now if I simply reload the psmouse module without any options, however did not work before (even if I remove changes described here). I do not know whether newest kernel made the difference.

If your touchpad not working, you must first try reloading module to see if that helps, try one of the command combinations below:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps

sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=bare

sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse resync_time=10
```

Reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184067